# Call different onChange method for slide toggle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am creating a simple toggle app that that has two toggles.I'm saving the toggle state in a db. My issue is that when  I toggle one slide-toggle,  the value of other slide toggle also changes.I have seperate onChnage() methods for both toggles but still I get the same issue.Please help.Thanks in advance:

Here is my ts code:

```
export class PolicyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() change: EventEmitter<MatSlideToggleChange>;
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  policy1: boolean=false;
  policy2: boolean=false;

  disable:boolean=true;
serverData:any
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private policyService:PolicyService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
 //   this.filteringSchedule = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('toggleButtonState'));

 this.policyService.getPolicy().subscribe(
  (response)=>{
    console.log(response);   

    this.serverData = response[0]; 
    console.log(this.serverData)
    if(this.serverData.policy1=="F")
    {
      this.policy1=false;
    }
    else this.policy1=true;

    if(this.serverData.policy2=="F")
    {
      this.policy2=false;
    }
    else this.policy2=true;



 }

 )

    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      Policy1:new FormControl( this.policy1,[]),
      Policy2: new FormControl( this.policy2,[])

    });

   // this.policyService.getUserById(+ localStorage.getItem("policyId")).subscribe();
}

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log("Policy1::"+this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.value);
    if(this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.value)
    {
      this.serverData.policy1="T";
    }
    else{
      this.serverData.policy1="F";
    }

    if(this.formGroup.controls.Policy2.value)
    {
      this.serverData.policy2="T";
    }
    else{
      this.serverData.policy2="F";
    }
    //this.policyService.updatePolicy(this.policy.id,{policy1:this.policy.policy1}).subscribe(err=>{console.log(err)});
    this.policyService.updateUser(this.serverData).subscribe(err=>{console.log(err)});
 //   alert(JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 2));
 this.disable=true;

  }

  onChange(ob: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.policy1 = !this.policy1;
    this.disable=false;
  }

  onChange1(ob: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.policy2 = !this.policy2;
    this.disable=false;
  }
}
```

Below is my template:

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" ngNativeValidate>
  <mat-action-list>
    <mat-list-item > <mat-slide-toggle       
      (change)="onChange($event)"  [checked]="policy1"  formControlName="Policy1" >Policy1</mat-slide-toggle></mat-list-item> 
    <mat-list-item > <mat-slide-toggle  (change)="onChange1($event)" [checked]="policy2" formControlName="Policy2">Policy2</mat-slide-toggle></mat-list-item>

  </mat-action-list>
  <p>Form Group Status: {{ formGroup.status}}</p>

  <button mat-rasied-button [disabled]="disable" type="submit">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have double binding to your `mat-slide-toggle` elements so Angular gets confused and it doesn't know which value to put there.

```
<mat-action-list>
   <mat-list-item > 
      <mat-slide-toggle (change)="onChange($event)"  
      [checked]="policy1" <----------------------------------first binding
      formControlName="Policy1"><----------------------------second binding
      Policy1</mat-slide-toggle>
   </mat-list-item> 
   <mat-list-item > 
      <mat-slide-toggle (change)="onChange1($event)" 
      [checked]="policy2" <----------------------------------first binding
      formControlName="Policy2"><----------------------------second binding
      Policy2</mat-slide-toggle>
   </mat-list-item>
</mat-action-list>
```

In my experience, it causes this trouble.
The right way of using reactive forms in Angular is using two ways binding by the property `formControlName="..."`, then when you build the form you should do:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        Policy1: new FormControl(false, []),
        Policy2: new FormControl(false, [])
    });
    this.policyService.getPolicy().subscribe((response) => {
        this.serverData = response[0];
        this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.setValue(this.serverData.policy1=="F");
        this.formGroup.controls.Policy2.setValue(this.serverData.policy2=="F");
    });
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<mat-action-list>
   <mat-list-item > 
      <mat-slide-toggle (change)="onChange($event)"  
      formControlName="Policy1"><----------------------------Only!!
      Policy1</mat-slide-toggle>
   </mat-list-item> 
   <mat-list-item > 
      <mat-slide-toggle (change)="onChange1($event)" 
      formControlName="Policy2"><----------------------------Only!!
      Policy2</mat-slide-toggle>
   </mat-list-item>
</mat-action-list>
```

Comment: But if I remove the checked property,how will I toggle the button based on db value?

Comment: The `formControlName` property is two ways binding, that means that when you change the form control value in your ts file the value will be updated in the UI part. So when you set the values from the DB into your form controls the elements will be toggled like the values.

Comment: It is not changing.I made the changes suggested by you but whenever I refresh the page,the toggle returns to it's default value. Am I missing something.Can you give me a stackblitz demo?

Comment: Can you debbug it and loook what happend when the values are returned from the server? the controls has the right values?

Comment: the correct values are being persisted from the server.However the toggle is not as per those values.Do I need to do some changes in the onChange() method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191975/discussion-between-m-s-and-rock11).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for your question

```
  <mat-card class="result">
  <mat-card-content>
    <h2 class="example-h2">Result</h2>

    <section class="example-section">
      <mat-slide-toggle
          [(ngModel)]="checked1"
          class="example-margin"
          [color]="color"
          (change)="changed()">
        Slide me! {{checked}}
      </mat-slide-toggle>

    </section>
     <mat-slide-toggle
          [(ngModel)]="checked2"
          class="example-margin"
          [color]="color"
          (change)="changed2()">
        Slide me! {{checked}}
      </mat-slide-toggle>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Here is the ts code

```
  export class SlideToggleConfigurableExample {
  color = 'accent';
  checked1 : boolean=true;
  checked2:boolean=false;
  disable:any;

  changed(){
  //  this.checked1 = !this.checked2;
    this.checked1=true;
  }
  changed2(){
    // this.checked1 = !this.checked2;
    this.checked2=false;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czuhgz)